# MATLAB/OCTAVE - Branching loops? or parallel looping?

Tags: matlab, octave

Still new to the programing game but I need a little help!  I'm not exactly sure how to describe what I want to do but I'll give it my best shot.  I have a set of numbers produced by an algorithm I've put together.  e.g. :

```
....
10 10 10
11 11 11
12 1 2
13 3 4
14 12 13
15 6 7
16 5 15
17 8 9
....
```

Essentially what I want to do is assign these index numbers to groups.  Lets say I start with the number 14 in the first column. It is going to belong to group 1, so I label it in a new column in row 14 "1" for group one.  The second and the third column show other index numbers that are grouped with the index 14.  So I use a code like:

```
 FindLHS = find(matrix(:,1)==matrix(14,2));
```

and
     FindRHS = find(matrix(:,1)==matrix(14,3));

so clearly this will produce the results of

```
FindLHS = 12
FindRHS = 13
```

I will then proceed to label both 12 and 13 as belonging to group "1" as I did for 14

now my problem is I want to do this same procedure for both 12 and 13 of finding and labelling the indexs for 12 and 13 being (1,2) and (3,4).  Is there a way to repeat that code for both idx of 1,2,3 and 4? because the real dataset has over 5000 data points in it...

Do you understand what I mean?

Thanks
James

Comment: Your last paragraph isn't that clear to me. `12 and 13 being (1,2) and (3,4)`? `(1,2)` makes some sense, but `(3,4)`? Also, `idx of 1,2,3 and 4`? Expand a little more on these?

Comment: ok, sorry.  I'm trying to emulate matlabs "cluster" function because I'm using octave and octave doesn't have that function.  Essentially the number in the first column "owns" or is "clustered with" the two numbers on its right (i.e. column 2 and 3).  Think of it as you will a tree diagram.  The number 14 is made up of the numbers stored in 12 and 13.  The number 12 is made from 1 and 2 and the number 13 is made from 3 and 4.  So in other words I start with 14 and I look at the two numbers 13 and 12.  I then look for those numbers in the first column to see what they have been grouped with

Comment: so in group 1 will be the numbers 14, 13, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4.  If I started at number 16 we can see that 16 has been grouped with numbers 5 and 15.  If we then search for the numbers 5 and 15 in the first column you would see (but I haven't included it in this list) 5 is grouped with itself so (5) and 15 is grouped with 6 and 7. So in group 2 is made from the numbers 16, 5, 15, 6 and 7.  I want a process that automates this

Comment: 4 Questions: 1) Do you want the output to be sorted? 2) Are the no. in row 1 sorted? 3) Is the entry in column 1 always higher than the ones in column 2 and 3? 4)If there is the same value in Column 2 and 3 do you want them to be listed each time or only ones?. Explanation to 4) E.g. 16 beeing constructed from 5 and 15 and lets say 29 beeing constructed from 15 and 16. Do you want 15 to be listed twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really want to do is find wherever `matrix(:,1)` contains one of the numbers you've already found, include the numbers in the second and third columns into your group list (presuming they aren't already there), and stop when that list stops growing, right?  This may not be the most efficient way of doing it but it gives you the basic idea:

```
while ~(numel(oldnum)==numel(num))

    oldnum = num;
    idx = ismember(matrix(:,1),oldnum)
    num = unique(matrix(idx,:))

end

Output:

num =

     1
     2
     3
     4
    12
    13
    14
```

Now if your first column is literally just your numbers 1 through 5000 in order, you don't need to even find the index,  you can just use your number list directly.

To do this for multiple groups you would just need an outer loop that stores the information for each group, then picks out the next unused number.  I'm presuming that your individual groups are consistent so that no matter which of those numbers you pick you end up with the same result - e.g. starting at 2 or 14 gives you the same result (if not, it becomes more complex).